# Is $\int_0^T\Delta_t^2(\omega)dt$ a Riemann integral or an Itô integral?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am studying stochastic integrals w.r.t. brownian motion and for a generic integrand process $\{\Delta_t\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ the following condition is required:
$E\big[\int_0^T\Delta_t^2(\omega)dt\big]<\infty$.

I don’t quite understand what kind of integral that is, and how would you assure the condition is satisfied for a specific process.

The same integral is also used to define the quadratic variation of the Itô integral:  $[I,I]_t(\omega)=\int_0^t\Delta^2_u(\omega)du$, a.s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We treat this integral as a path-by-path Riemann or Lebesgue integral. It is **not** an Itô integral. To get the quadratic variation, one fixes $\omega \in \Omega$, and obtains a single trajectory of the process: $$t \mapsto \Delta_t^2(\omega)$$ To this trajectory, we may assign an integral $$[I,I]_t(\omega) = \int_0^t \Delta_u^2(\omega )du$$
which is interpreted in the Riemann sense if possible, or Lebesgue integral (against the Lebesgue measure) if necessary. Observe now that $[I,I]$ is a stochastic process, so that its expectation is simply the integral against the background probability measure.

Comment: Thank you. How can we compute the expectation of that integral for a fixed t=T and verify that it’s finite? For example let’s say $\{\Delta_t\}$ is a brownian motion. (I’m referring to the condition for the generic integrand process of the Itô integral now)

Comment: @Andrei There's not much one can say in general other than $E \left[ \int_0^t \Delta_u^2 du \right] = \int_0^t E[\Delta_u^2] du$, which is due to Tonelli's theorem. You would have to consider each integrand individually to decide how to best compute the expectation. If $\Delta$ is Brownian motion you get: $\int_0^t E[\Delta_u^2] du = \int_0^t u du = \frac{t^2}{2}$